# Parsing PDF file using PHP to submit values to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I want to know if it is possible to view a PDF file in a webapp of some kind, then be able to trace over lines in the PDF file and submit the lengths to an MySQL database.
Basically import a PDF file, trace around a shape in that PDF file and save those values.

I work with House plans and this would make my job a lot easier.

Is it possible? and can someone point me in the right direction on where to read more.
I know its possible to pull text from a PDF file, I've seen heaps of info on how to do that using various libraries, but nothing on a Vector shape (house plan).

If it's not possible in PHP which language should I look into, the only reason I ask is because I have basic skills in PHP and have already written some simple apps that help me out, this would just be the final touch to make my job easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Parsing PDFs is a world of pain... And PHP is probably as good language to jump into this as any other. 
I would recommend you to start your research with [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/), it has a CLI interface which could be accessed by php